# Trace of a matrix

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, trace

"the preceding 2 scalar solutions correspond to the vector solutions $x^1(t)=(t,1)^T$ and $x^2(t)=(t^2,2t)^T$ which have the Wronskian

$$W(t)=\det\left[\begin{array}{lr}
\mbox t & t^2\\
\mbox 1 & 2t \\
\end{array}\right]=t^2$$

on the other hand the trace of the matrix of coefficients is $2/t$, so for $t$, $t_0>0$

I am confused about how they got the book got that answer for the trace, I thought the trace was the sum of the diagonal? t+2t=3t? What am I missing?

Comment: You say that the trace of the matrix of coefficients is $2/t.$ No that the trace of the Wronskian is $2/t.$

Comment: @mfl oh ok, what is the matrix of coefficients in this case? the original equation was $t^2y"-2ty'+2y=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ODE $t^2y"-2ty'+2y=0$ can be written as $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\begin{array}{c} y \\ y' \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1 \\ -\frac{2}{t^2} & \frac 2t \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} y \\ y' \end{array}\right).$$ Here, the matrix of coefficients is $$\left(\begin{array}{rr} 0 & 1 \\ -\frac{2}{t^2} & \frac 2t \end{array}\right)$$ with trace $2/t$ as the book says.

Comment: so $t^2y"-2ty'+2y=0$ and then dividing by $t^2$ I get $y"=(2/t)y'-(2/t^2)y$ Is this how you get the answers for the first matrix? And then how did you get the "1" in the first line? I guess I am confused about how you got the answer for how to rewrite the ODE in that matrix form, and also what the motivation behind wanting to do that is

Comment: The first line of the matrix just corresponds to $dy=dt=0y+1y'.$ The second one is what you have said, $y"=(2/t)y'-(2/t^2)y.$

Comment: Oh ok, so I guess I don't understand what is the point of doing this? What does it show?

Comment: The Wronskian satisfies the differential equation $dW/dt=\mathrm{trace}(A)W.$ Using it, once you know a solution of the ODE, you can get a new solution linearly independent. See http://www.mth.uct.ac.za/~jratzkin/class-notes/2nd-order-de-B.pdf and http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116C/Wronskian_12.pdf